# How to build a dynamic model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am building an editable user-form using Ruby on Rails. I currently have a model to store the question title and a separate model to store options for each question.

The form has a list of all the questions and for each question, the user can view the form in a drop down list.

My problem is that I want to create a model for a user that can select an option for each questions and I want to store these options for each user in the database. If the manager deletes a question from the questions table, then the user form will not have that question.

[image: List of questions and options]

And I am displaying a form to the user showing these questions by means of a form: [image: Survey Questions]

But I do not know how to create a model to store answer for all the questions for different users of the system. Can someone suggest how to create such a dynamic model?

Comment: can you add the current association among `user`, `question` and `options/answer`.

Comment: Hi @dkp can you explain what you mean? I mean currently I do not have a user, I have create a model for him. But I have a one->many association between questions and options.

Comment: I would have created another model say `UserAnswer` with attributes `question_id` and `option_id`. Association could look like as: `Question has_many :user_answers` , `Option has_many :user_answers` , `UserAnswer belongs_to :question` , `UserAnswer belongs_to :option` .  Later on if you create `User` model, then just add another attribute `user_id` to `UserAnswer` model.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dkp I will work on this now